# Integrating Timer Control from StartPomodoro Widget into GNav Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I'm developing a timer application in Flutter and I've encountered an issue with restructuring my UI. Specifically, I need to move the start/pause button from the `StartPomodoro` widget to a `GNav` widget in my `HomePageTimerUI` while maintaining the timer's functionality and controlling animations.

Here's the layout I currently have:

[image]

And here's what I'm aiming to achieve:

[image]

The challenge arises because my `StartPomodoro` page contains all the logic for controlling the timer and animations. When I try to cut and paste the start widget into the `HomePageTimerUI`, I can't seem to integrate it properly.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

*HomePageTimerUI.dart*

```
class HomePageTimerUI extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePageTimerUI({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<HomePageTimerUI> createState() => _HomePageTimerUIState();
}

class _HomePageTimerUIState extends State<HomePageTimerUI>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TabController _tabController;

  late Timer timer;
  late AnimationController controller;

  String get countText {
    Duration count = controller.duration! * controller.value;
    return controller.isDismissed
        ? '${controller.duration!.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(controller.duration!.inMinutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(controller.duration!.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}'
        : '${count.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(count.inMinutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(count.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(length: 3, vsync: this);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void notify() {
    if (countText == '00:00:00') {
      _tabController.animateTo(1, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300));
    }
  }

  @override
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 600,
        width: double.infinity,
        child: DefaultTabController(
            length: 3,
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                elevation: 0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                bottom: PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(55),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: SafeArea(
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          TabBar(
                              controller: _tabController,
                              indicator: UnderlineTabIndicator(
                                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                                      color: Color(0xff3B3B3B), width: 4.0),
                                  insets: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                      12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 11.0)),
                              indicatorWeight: 15,
                              indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
                              labelColor: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                              labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 12,
                                  letterSpacing: 1.3,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                              unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xffD7D7D7),
                              tabs: [
                                Tab(
                                  text: "POMODORO",
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.work_history, size: 40),
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "SHORT BREAK",
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.ramen_dining, size: 40),
                                ),
                                Tab(
                                  text: "LONG BREAK",
                                  icon: Icon(
                                      Icons.battery_charging_full_rounded,
                                      size: 40),
                                ),
                              ])
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              body: TabBarView(
                controller: _tabController,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child: StartPomodoro(),
                  ),
                  // Center(
                  //   child: ShortBreak(),
                  // ),
                  // Center(child: LongBreak()),
                ],
              ),
              bottomNavigationBar: Container(
                height: 110,
                color: Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20),
                  child: GNav(
                    iconSize: 40,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    backgroundColor: Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                    color: Color(0xffD7D7D7),
                    activeColor: Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                    tabBackgroundColor: Color(0xffF0F0F0),
                    gap: 8,
                    onTabChange: (index) {
                      print(index);
                    },
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),
                    tabs: [
                      GButton(
                        icon: Icons.settings,
                        text: 'Settings',
                      ),
                      GButton(
                        icon: Icons.person,
                        text: "Profile",
                      ),
                      GButton(
                        icon: Icons.task,
                        text: "Tasks",
                      ),
                      GButton(
                        icon: Icons.show_chart,
                        text: "Performance",
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

*startpomodoro.dart*

```
class StartPomodoro extends StatefulWidget {
  const StartPomodoro({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<StartPomodoro> createState() => _StartPomodoroState();
}

class _StartPomodoroState extends State<StartPomodoro>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
      
  List<bool> isSelected = [true, false];
  late Timer timer;
  late AnimationController controller;

  String get countText {
    Duration count = controller.duration! * controller.value;
    return controller.isDismissed
        ? '${controller.duration!.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(controller.duration!.inMinutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(controller.duration!.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}'
        : '${count.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(count.inMinutes % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}:${(count.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }

  double progress = 1.0;
  bool LongBreak = true;

  void notify() {
    if (countText == '00:00:00') {}
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 0),
    );
    controller.addListener(() {
      notify();
      if (controller.isAnimating) {
        setState(() {
          progress = controller.value;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          progress = 1.0;
          LongBreak = true;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    
    ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return Scaffold(
              backgroundColor:
                  LongBreak ? const Color(0xffD94530) : const Color(0xff6351c5),
              body: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  if (controller.isDismissed) {
                    showModalBottomSheet(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) => Container(
                        height: 300,
                        child: CupertinoTimerPicker(
                          initialTimerDuration: controller.duration!,
                          onTimerDurationChanged: (time) {
                            setState(() {
                              controller.duration = time;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                },
                child: AnimatedBuilder(
                    animation: controller,
                    builder: (context, child) {
                      return Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            child: Container(
                              color: const Color(0xffD94530),
                              height: controller.value *
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                  0.640,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                    child: Align(
                                      alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Text(
                                              countText,
                                              style: const TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 90.0,
                                                color: Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Column(
                                  
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                    children: [
                                      AnimatedBuilder(
                                          animation: controller,
                                          builder: (context, child) {
                                            return const Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                  vertical: 2.0,
                                                  horizontal: 15.0),
                                            );
                                          }),
                                      AnimatedBuilder(
                                          animation: controller,
                                          builder: (context, child) {
                                            return Padding(
                                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                  vertical: 2.0,
                                                  horizontal: 15.0),
                                              child:
                                                  FloatingActionButton.extended(
                                                      backgroundColor:
                                                          const Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                                                      onPressed: () {
                                                        if (controller
                                                            .isAnimating) {
                                                          controller.stop();
                                                          setState(() {
                                                            LongBreak = false;
                                                          });
                                                        } else {
                                                          controller.reverse(
                                                              from: controller
                                                                          .value ==
                                                                      0
                                                                  ? 1.0
                                                                  : controller
                                                                      .value);
                                                          setState(() {
                                                            LongBreak = false;
                                                          });
                                                        }
                                                      },
                                                      icon: Icon(
                                                        controller.isAnimating
                                                            ? Icons.pause
                                                            : Icons.play_arrow,
                                                        color:
                                                            const Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                                      ),
                                                      label: Text(
                                                        controller.isAnimating
                                                            ? "Pause"
                                                            : "Start",
                                                        style: const TextStyle(
                                                            color: Color(
                                                                0xff3B3B3B)),
                                                      )),
                                            );
                                          }),
                                      const SizedBox(width: 20, height: 100),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            );}
 
}
```

How can I replace the start/pause button into the `GNav` widget while maintaining its height and also initialize the timer correctly in this new structure?

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to precisely figure out from the code produced. Because of too many widgets and wrong indentations. I would give suggestions based on rough insights.

If you want to seperate two elements use `Spacer` that will do the job for you, Otherwise try the following approach.

#### Present approach (roughly)

```
Column
 |_ Timer Container
 |_ Floating button
```

to

#### Correct appraoch

```
Column
 |_ Expanded
   |_ Center
     |_ Timer Container
 |_ Floating Button
```